# Screen mirroring with Chromecast on apps that disallow it

Tags: applications, chromecast

I currently have a Chromecast and a Sony Xperia Z3

The problem that I am having is using some apps with screen mirroring; 4od and Sky Go. If you are not from the UK then these are apps for watching television.

When I use the Chromecast app and try to mirror my screen whilst using these apps I get a message that these apps don't support screen mirroring.

I have done a bit of research and I have found that an app called #MirrorEnabler that I think would do the job, however it would require rooting my phone which I don't really want to do.

Does anyone know a work around for this? Maybe a different screen mirroring app that the 4od and Sky Go won't detect?

Comment: The only other method I know of is using Xposed modules, but obviously that requires rooting as well.